# Insert into Access table from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

Can anyone tell me how to insert data from SQL Server into an existing MS Access table? I would be using MS Access 2010 and SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In SSMS go to *Server Objects, Linked Servers*.

Create here a connection to your Access file.

Create a view in your SQL database with the Access table as source using the triple-dot syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourLinkedDatabase...YourAccessTable AS AliasOfYourChoice
```

Now, use this view to easily address the Access table from your SQL database.

Note that you most likely will need exclusive access to the Access database.